# AbstractPreferences equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, java, equivalent

Is there any class or analog for work with Base64 in c# like AbstractPreferences in java?

Comment: I'm not sure what `AbstractPreferences` does but see if [`Convert.ToBase64String()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) and [`Convert.FromBase64String()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) would be of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert.ToBase64String http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx
Convert.FromBase64String http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx